# Некорректная ссылка для первоначальной установки. Локальная встройка виджетов с помощью REST API Bitrix24

Tags: php, rest, битрикс24, настройки, веб-интерфейс

Я хочу встроить пункт меню в карточку контакта CRM. Я действовал согласно [REST API. Локальная встройка виджетов](https://vk.com/video-211967493_456239887). Скачал архив с [Встройка виджета в Битрикс24](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=266&LESSON_ID=25522&LESSON_PATH=25398.25506.25512.25522) - `examples12.zip` (в конце страницы, в материалах к уроку) и поместил его содержимое в папку `D:\OSPanel\domains\restexamples12`.

Перешел на (`Приложения -> Разработчикам -> Встроить виджет`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем на (`Приложения -> Разработчикам -> Встроить виджет -> Вывести свои данные в карточку CRM`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После заполнил параметры для виджета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее нажимаю кнопку **`Сохранить`** и получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получил ошибку - **Некорректная ссылка для первоначальной установки.** Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

Путь `https://restexamples12/placement.php` существует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуглил [Некорректная ссылка для первоначальной установки.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8.&sca_esv=595112324&sxsrf=AM9HkKnfb1ZoGusiXya63GJ0u35SS4pHqw%3A1704214786528&ei=AkGUZYzwH9uawPAPpq2j6As&ved=0ahUKEwiM-eLnlr-DAxVbDRAIHabWCL0Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8.&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiXdCd0LXQutC-0YDRgNC10LrRgtC90LDRjyDRgdGB0YvQu9C60LAg0LTQu9GPINC_0LXRgNCy0L7QvdCw0YfQsNC70YzQvdC-0Lkg0YPRgdGC0LDQvdC-0LLQutC4LjIEECMYJ0jOIFDvDViTFnACeAGQAQCYAYgDoAGIA6oBAzMtMbgBA8gBAPgBAfgBAqgCFMICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgcQIxjqAhgnwgIUEAAYgAQY4wQY6QQY6gIYtALYAQHCAhYQABgDGI8BGOUCGOoCGLQCGIwD2AECwgIWEC4YAxiPARjlAhjqAhi0AhiMA9gBAuIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgi6BgYIARABGAG6BgYIAhABGAs&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) - ничего не нашел.

Comment: Если Вы о URL обработчика виджета, то проблема вполне может быть в том, что вот это: `https://restexamples12/placement.php` не выглядит как корректный URL адрес.

Comment: @Simon А в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Там банально может быть правило валидации, которое проверяет валидность URL при помощи `filter_var()` или `filter_input()` с флагом [FILTER_VALIDATE_URL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), ну либо какое-то другое правило, которое проверяет наличие доменной зоны или точки и что после нее что-то есть. Можете наглядно посмотреть [как это работает](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_validate_url)

Comment: @Simon спасибо огромное, помогло.